# Do we need to call foursquare Venue Categories API at regular interval?

Tags: foursquare

Please let me know whether we have to call foursquare  [Venue Categories API](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories) at regular interval

or we have to call only once so that we can store category list in database and use them for searching items

If category Id is not getting changed in the above scenario , it will work for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you should call the categories endpoint at a regular interval**, but that interval can be large.

They make changes to the categories - we call it once a month or so (manually actually), to update the hierarchy that we cache on our side.

We have not seen a category ID changes, but rather more categories are added over time, and maybe removed (not really sure about removed)

It happens rarely, but we sometimes have an error when we can a category id that we do not recognize and then we need to go refresh the categories list and rebuild our cache.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Levison  . Could you please let me know whether parent category ID is getting changed over time .
For Ex. If there is a parent category  "Food" and its child categories are "Indian Restaurant " and "Asian Restaurant " , in that case , please let me know whether category Id of food would be changed or it would remain same .

Comment: This answer cannot be 100% fact, because foursquare may choose to change the ID someday (although that would make little sense). I can tell you that for the last year in which we have been using the API it has been `4d4b7105d754a06374d81259` and did not change. In our database, we did not map our data to `4d4b7105d754a06374d81259`, but to an internal id (82 in that matter), so if foursquare chooses to change it, it will have little consequences on our engine.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Levison . That makes sense

Answer (score 1):

From the API docs (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories):

"...please download this list only once per session, but also avoid caching this data for longer than a week to avoid stale information."

So, you can store the list in your database, but you should refresh this data at least once a week.